# How can I run a jupyter notebook with an nvidia gpu (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nvidia, ubuntu-18.04

A classmate of mine told me it was possible to run a particularly slow piece of code with my laptop's nvidia gpu (GeForce  GTX 1050), but I'm having a hard time finding anything about it online. How would one configure a jupyter notebook tu run on an nvidia gpu on Ubuntu 18.04.02?

Comment: you can run some codes like tensor-flow etc on GPUs as such you can't run jupyter notebook on GPU

Comment: for some examples on how to put certain parts on GPU consider this link::https://weeraman.com/put-that-gpu-to-good-use-with-python-e5a437168c01

Comment: Thank you! I'll read up on it and try to adapt my code